# javascript date format conversion error

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript

```
new Date("12-03-2018")
```

returns me Dec 03 2018.

But I was expecting Mar 12 2018

Is there any way to specify the date format as DD-MM-YYYY, seems it is taking it as MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: Did you mean March 12?  "12-03-2018" can't possibly be interpreted as "March 03"

Comment: Sorry yes, March 12

Comment: parse string and use values separate `new Date(2018, 2, 12)`

Comment: @MysterX Thanks, mate, no other simple way?

Comment: [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): _"The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (**[IETF-compliant RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14)** timestamps and also a version of **[ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)**)."_

Comment: MomentJS lets you parse from a specific format, in a cross-browser consistent way.

Comment: @MysterX you mean `new Date(2018, 2, 12)` - month is zero-indexed ;)

Comment: @phuzi yep, exactly. comment edited

Comment: Please search before you ask. This question has been answered a gazillion times already.

Comment: Thanks, guys, moment js helped me. Sorry for duplicate post, I could not find before.